# Eclipse and Ant integration

Tags: eclipse, ant, classpath

Is there a way for my eclipse project to inherit the build classpath from existing Ant build.xml files? It would be nice if I didn't have to keep the eclipse project and the ant build in sync!

Answer (score 1):

Off-hand, I'd say no, but see here http://www.ant4eclipse.org/node/6 for an attempt at doing the opposite (keeping the Ant build path in sync with Eclipse). Maybe that's of some use?

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it's a good idea to have the build system dependent on any particular IDE.

Comment: I tend to agree. That said, the notion of "the classpath" is somewhat nebulous is ant, since you can use different classpaths for different tasks. One recommendation might be to look at Ivy, if you don't mind modifying the build files (Ivy has good integration with both Eclipse and Ant).

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be is for both ant and eclipse to point to a common file specifying dependencies, independent from both ant and eclipse.

You can do this with ivy (http://ant.apache.org/ivy/), which has both tasks for ant and a eclipse ide plugin. ivy also solves the third-party library dependency management problem (you create a central repository of all third-party dependencies in your company which are pulled down as needed, rather than keeping .jar files with each project).

It takes a little time to create the initial ivy repository by copying libraries from maven, but is well worth it longer-term.